# Maya name clash with FBX motion capture file and FBX avatar on the 'root'

Tags: character, maya, motion-capture

I'm attempting to re-target motion capture data from radical motion to an avatar I created with Character Creator. After creating a character definition for one, I import the other and it appears they are merging their 'roots'. Both their hierarchies contain a `:root` with no namespace. I tried modifying namespaces before importing but that isn't working either.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my import settings for my FBX files. Under Include -> File Content, I needed to select Add. More info can be found [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Maya-DataExchange/files/GUID-0CD41066-4C27-48AE-9776-366DB11B4FDF-htm.html).